# geom_abline isn't plotting properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which I have plotted as a box plot and added a regression line. I want to compare this regression line with another line (from a different experiment) which I am putting in using geom_abline. But as you can see, the abline isn't at the correct position. Am I missing something?

[image]

```
    eq <- function(x,y) {
  m <- lm(log10Vol ~ log10hpf, Cell.Volume.Calculations)
  as.character(
    as.expression(
      substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2,
                 list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 4),
                      b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 4),
                      r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
    )
  )
}


    logEmb_hpff = ggplot(data = Cell.Volume.Calculations, aes(x=reorder(log10hpf,-Volume), y=log10Vol, fill=Stage)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.4) +
  #scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "J", alpha = 0.7)+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Stage), size=1, alpha=1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(group=1), se = TRUE, color = "gray60", alpha = 0.1)+
  geom_text(x = 4.5, y = 7.5, label = eq(Cell.Volume.Calculations$log10hpf, Cell.Volume.Calculations$log10Vol), parse = TRUE, color = "grey40") +
  #stat_regline_equation(label.y = 100, aes(label = ..eq.label..))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_test() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=14),
    strip.text.x = element_text(
      size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"
    ))# +
  #ggtitle("Cell Volumes for Early Embryo") +
 # xlab("log10(hours post fertilisation)")+
  #ylab("Single Cell Volume [log10(micron cubed)]")
logEmb_hpff + geom_abline(mapping = aes(intercept = 8.024, slope = -3, color = "red"))
```

Comment: The issue is that `reorder(log10hpf,-Volume)` is a factor. Hence your x-axis category "0" (which is the second category of this factor) corresponds to a numeric value of 2. Therefore the y value of the abline shown for category "0" is 8.024 - 3 * 2 = 2.024. A simple example to illustrate the issue: `df <- data.frame(x = -1:1, y = 3:1); ggplot(df, aes(reorder(x, -y), y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(group = 1)) + geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = -1, color = "red")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed the reorder argument and just put log10hpf. It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stefan has solved the problem in the comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).